# how can I sort company list based on Name ascending, descending order in my adapter?

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin

I am developing new app and how can I  sort the company list based on Name ascending, descending order in my adapter?.

below my Adapter class

```
class SpectrumAdapter(
    private val spectrumResponse: ArrayList <SpectrumResponseItem>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SpectrumViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SpectrumViewHolder {

        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.spectrum_list, parent, false)
        return SpectrumViewHolder(view)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return spectrumResponse.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SpectrumViewHolder, position: Int) {
        return holder.bind(spectrumResponse[position])
    }
}
```

the adapter class.

```
    class SpectrumViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        private val companyLogo: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.companyLogo)
        private val companyName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.companyName)
        private val companyWebsite: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.companyWebsite)

        fun bind(spectrum: SpectrumResponseItem) {
            Glide.with(itemView.context).load(R.drawable.placehold).into(companyLogo)

            companyName.text = spectrum.company
            companyWebsite.text = spectrum.website
        }

    }
```

below list XML layout

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/companyLogo"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/companyWebsite"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/companyName"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/companyWebsite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="Company Website"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/companyLogo"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/companyLogo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/companyName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="286dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="286dp"
            android:text="Company Name"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/companyLogo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I want to implement sorting function where user can sort companyName ascending and descending order how can I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add method sortAscending and sortDescending in your adapter. But you need to change your `private val spectrumResponse: ArrayList` to `var` because the data can be changed while sorting. here is full code example for adapter.

```
class SpectrumAdapter(
    private var spectrumResponse: ArrayList <SpectrumResponseItem>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SpectrumViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SpectrumViewHolder {

        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.spectrum_list, parent, false)
        return SpectrumViewHolder(view)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return spectrumResponse.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SpectrumViewHolder, position: Int) {
        return holder.bind(spectrumResponse[position])
    }

    fun sortAscending() {
        spectrumResponse = spectrumResponse.sortedBy { it.name }
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun sortDescending() {
        spectrumResponse = spectrumResponse.sortedByDescending { it.name }
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
 
}
```

then you can call it in your button on you activity like this.

```
btn_sort_ascending.setOnClickListener {
    adapter.sortAscending()
}
```

the `btn_sort_ascending` is the view id of your button.
the `adapter` is your created adapter.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer  can I ask a question I want to filter button or switch add where user can sort ascending or descending order where I have to add it in list or activity XML where I have host recyclerview.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer  can I ask a question I want to filter button or switch add where user can sort ascending or descending order where I have to add it in list or activity XML where I have host recyclerview.

Comment: Do you need to implement different filter function to multiple activity? if so then I suggest to create a method in your adapter to filter the list, then pass the criteria in the parameter when it's called. I edit my answer to show the example.

Comment: Najat, now only I want to implemented filter where user can sort companyName ascending and descending order if you need my mainactivity and XML I can put as well

Comment: Oh Sorry, I thought you need some special filter. If you say so then you need to add listener to the button. When the button is clicked just call sortAscending function from the adapter. You can call it like this 

`btn_sort_ascending.setOnClickListener {
    adapter.sortAscending()
}
`

Comment: Yes I mean your mainActivity.

Comment: I have to call in my main activity right your mean can I post my mainactivity i want to add sortAscending and sortDescendingButton over there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219628/discussion-between-miftahun-najat-and-edgar-davids).